# как мне сделать переход на другую страницу?

Tags: python, django

Есть сайт.  Есть страница хтмл [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там где "о нас" хочу сделать что бы было кликабельно и переходило собственно, на эту самую страницу.

файл страницы хтмл залила в проект,  но не работает, выдает Page not found (404)
код ссылки:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'shop:about' %}">О нас</a>
```

(лежит в папке shop, файл называется about)

Comment: куда именно залили файл? Вероятно, куда-то не туда, вот и не находит его, либо url не правильный

Answer (score 1):

Юрл задан для нее?

```
path('about/', views.AboutUsView.as_view(), name='about'),
```

Вьюшка написана для ее вывода?

```
class AboutUsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

Следует еще проверить порядок юрл, что нет конфликтов. Например если юрл принимает именя пользователей по типу ниже.
Данный пример работать не будет, так как будет искать пользователя с юзернеймом about. И path c about следует расположить выше.

```
 path('about/', views.AboutUsView.as_view(), name='about'),
```

Comment: я всё сделала так как мы написали но не выходит :((

Comment: /onlineshop-master/shop/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    path("<str:username>/", views.profile, name="profile"),
AttributeError: module 'shop.views' has no attribute 'profile'  ошибка(

Comment: Вы скопировали мой path из примера, который предназначен для просмотра профиля пользователя. На что вам джанга и говорит, что у вас нет функции с именем profie во views.py.
path пишется в urls.py, а во views.py уже class AboutUsView(TemplateView): и далее в template_name адрес до вашего файла html.

Comment: Удалите из `urls.py` строчку `path("<str:username>/", views.profile, name="profile"),`. Сам `about.html` ещё надо перенести в каталог `shop/templates`.